# Karate Gatling Project - AbstractMethodError

Tags: karate

I am running the karate gatling sample program under Gatling version 3.0.3.
I got this error when I want to call KarateProtocol.

*val pro = karateProtocol()
val auth = scenario("custom").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/AuthenticateUser.feature"))*

16:20:30.269 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateProtocol$$anon$1.newComponents(Lio/gatling/core/CoreComponents;)Lscala/Function1;
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$1(Protocol.scala:68)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.componentsFactory$1(Protocol.scala:68)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:70)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:72)
        at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateActionBuilder.build(KarateActionBuilder.scala:9)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.$anonfun$build$1(StructureBuilder.scala:35)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:34)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder.build$(StructureBuilder.scala:33)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(ScenarioBuilder.scala:38)
        at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(ScenarioBuilder.scala:100)
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:286)
        at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:194)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:92)
        at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:61)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:74)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:47)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using Java 8 ? This is fixed in the `develop` branch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/647

Otherwise please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/647

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was because the gatling changes some method signatures and it got fixed now. Thank you!